# deleting duplicate objects from taskbar

Tags: delete, taskbar, version

I am using Gnome 3 (I think) and I accidently put several icons for "computer" on the taskbar. How do I get rid of them and anything else I do not want on the taskbar. \

Also, how do I tell what version of Gnome I am using?

Comment: Can you add a Screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right-Click.